# I want compute $ \sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac {\left( 2n+k-2\right) !\zeta \left( 2n\right) \left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{\left( 2\pi \right) ^{2n}} $

Tags: summation, divergent-series

I want compute $ \sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac {\left( 2n+k-2\right) !\zeta \left( 2n\right) \left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{\left( 2\pi \right) ^{2n}} $

this series is surely not converge for any value of k,but even it is diverge series,we shall assign value for this series by cesaro,abel,borel etc sums but ı could not go any further

Comment: Why would anybody want to do that? Is there a special reason to calculate a number you can't even define properly?

Comment: ı was trying to prove a hypotessiss that explain how infinitly two- dimensional area works after  ı reached this point and could not find out a sollution for k so ı realized I gotta get help from experts

Comment: No. If you want to make it a true mathematical question, find a regularization method adapted to some divergent series whose coefficients have factorial growth.

Comment: what method  would you suggest me to apply?or is there any sample that can  be adapthed or generalized so far?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Since the terms diverge about as fast as $n^{2n}$, Abel and Cesaro summing will not work, but modified versions of the Borel sum might.

Comment: For $k=0$ I get using a Noerlund-type of summation   something like $0.04053073296..$

Comment: Reading this *"every mathematician would wanna compute it if they knew what it is for"* and considering the zero-amount of work to make this question worth for the MSE-platform (...fill in some criteria from the online-help...) I'm tempted to vote for close.

Comment: I am sorry,I dont know english much that is why I avoid explaining my steps ,technical english is still hard to me